# How to slice a string in Python using a dictionary containing character positions?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary containing the character positions of different fields in a string.  I'd like to use that information to slice the string.  I'm not really sure how to best explain this, but the example should make it clear:

input:

```
mappings = {'name': (0,4), 'job': (4,11), 'color': (11, 15)}
data = "JohnChemistBlue"
```

desired output:

```
{'name': 'John', 'job': 'Chemist', 'color': 'Blue'}
```

Please disregard the fact that jobs, colors and names obviously vary in character length.  I'm parsing fixed-length fields but simplified it here for illustrative purposes.

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but [Dictionaries aren't kept in order](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> dict([(k, data[ mappings[k][0]:mappings[k][1] ]) for k in mappings])
{'color': 'Blue', 'job': 'Chemist', 'name': 'John'}
```

or with a generator instead of a list (probably more efficient):

```
>>> dict(((k, data[ mappings[k][0]:mappings[k][1] ]) for k in mappings))
{'color': 'Blue', 'job': 'Chemist', 'name': 'John'}
```

Answer (score 10):

```
>>> dict((f, data[slice(*p)]) for f, p in mappings.iteritems())
{'color': 'Blue', 'job': 'Chemist', 'name': 'John'}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
dict([(name, data[range[0]:range[1]]) for name, range in mappings.iteritems()])
```

Comment: or {name: data[r[0]:r[1]] for name, r in mappings.items()}

Comment: I wish I could accept two answers. lol.  You guys were only a minute apart, so I have to go with the first.  I appreciate the help though!